# Updating different fields based on whether or not other fields have values

Tags: php, mysql

The query below works just fine.  I would like it to do the following:

- Update `flag1 = '$uflag'` only if flag1 is empty.
- Update `flag2 = '$uflag'` only if flag1 had a value in it and flag2 is empty.
- Update `flag3 = '$uflag'` only if flag1 and flag2 have values in them and flag3 is empty.

How could I do this?

```
UPDATE submission SET votes_up = $votes_up, flag1 = '$uflag'  WHERE submissionid = $id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your query simple, you could determine which SQL to utilize in PHP using conditions prior to the SQL's execution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
UPDATE submission
SET votes_up = $votes_up,
    flag1 = '$uflag',
    flag2 = IF(flag1 != '' AND flag2 = '','$uflag',flag2)
WHERE submissionid = $id
```

i.e. "update" flag2 to its previous value when conditions aren't met.

Comment: Remember the quotes and escaping. ;)